# Yii2 / nav bar / Hiding property of non-object

Tags: object, authentication, visibility, yii2

In old version of Yii this part of navbar code is working while user is not logged in.

```
array('label'=>Yii::t('ge',Yii::app()->user->name), 'url'=>array('/site/index'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

In Yii2

```
['label' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username, 'url' => ['site/index'], 'visible'=>!Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
```

Throws "Trying to get property of non-object" meaning that object `Yii::$app->user->identity->username` does not exists.

How can I fix this problem ? And why old version is working OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use :

```
'label' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? 'Guest' : Yii::$app->user->identity->username
```

Or extends `\yii\web\User` to handle this.

In Yii2 :

> @property IdentityInterface|null $identity The identity object associated with the currently logged-in user. **`null` is returned if the user is not logged in (not authenticated)**.

In Yii1, `CWebUser` provides default name. Feel free to ask this feature for Yii2 here : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues

**EDIT** : if you just want to hide this menu item for guests, add this to your item :

```
'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
```

Comment: But if I want to hide this label totally if user is not logged in ?

Comment: I mean in your answer this menu items is created and shows label guest or username, depending on IF step. But in old yii the whole menu item had options to show itself or not depending on user login status. So is it possible to completely do not show this menu item if user is guest ?